# Postfix: unused parameter for mysql maps

Tags: linux, mysql, postfix

I need to re-configure Postfix from scratch. When I configured on version 2.11.8-1.4 everything worked fine.
Now I am configuring version 3.3.1 on openSUSE Leap 15.0. I noticed that when postfix works with mysql, postfix complains about "unused" parameters in the logs. For example,

```
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_maps.cf: unused parameter: user=postfix
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_maps.cf: unused parameter: hosts=localhost
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/relay_domains_maps.cf: unused parameter: dbname=postfix
```

I checked MySQL maps with postmap -q. Everything OK and I got the string of domain.

I looked at the postfix site how to connect postfix and mysql. I wrote down the parameters in the main.conf for connecting the cards correctly.
The MySQL main.cf section looks like this:

```
############################################################
# Start MySQL from postfixwiki.org
############################################################
#relay_domains = $mydestination, hash:/etc/postfix/relay
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/relay_domains_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_alias_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf
#virtual_alias_domains = 
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:303
virtual_gid_maps = static:303
virtual_minimum_uid = 303
virtual_mailbox_base = /srv/maildirs
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
#virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
#virtual_mailbox_limit_inbox = no
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
## For dovecot LMTP replace 'virtual' with 'lmtp:unixrivate/dovecot-lmtp'
#virtual_transport = virtual
## Additional for quota support
#virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
#virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
### Needs Maildir++ compatible IMAP servers, like Courier-IMAP
#virtual_maildir_filter = yes
#virtual_maildir_filter_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vfilter
#virtual_maildir_limit_message = Sorry, the user's maildir has overdrawn his diskspace quota, please try again later.
#virtual_maildir_limit_message_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmsg
#virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
#virtual_trash_count = yes
#virtual_trash_name = ".Trash"
############################################################
# End MySQL from postfixwiki.org
############################################################
```

In the system error logs is not recorded. Only in the postfix job log after it is initialized are these warnings. I guess, postfix works fine, but what it is?

UPDATE:
Content of relay_domains_maps.cf:

```
user = postfix
password = pass
hosts = localhost
#hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = postfix
#table = domain
#select_field = domain
#where_field = domain
#additional_conditions = and backupmx = '1'
query = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' and backupmx='1'
```

SQL map's files were preinstalled. I just changed the values to the right.

Comment: Did you edit those files on a Windows PC?

Comment: No, I edited them in the vi on a server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Contents of my same, working file.  On postfix 3.1.0 from Ubuntu

```
user = mailserveruser
password = supersecret123
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserverdbtables
query = SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s'
```

Without you posting the contents of your file (be sure to change password to something obviously sample, feel free to do same wtih user, host, and db name)

Comment: I added to the question the contents of one of my cards. The parameters are set the same as yours, but I still get warnings from the postfix. This is normal?

Answer (score -1):

Same problem on opensuse 15.1!

Maybe use 
"proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf"

instead of

"mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf" only.

But it didn't solve the problem for me by the same problem on opensuse 15.1.

I tried postmap -q  mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf
to verify the configuration.

Answer / result was as expected. So it seems, Postfix has a problem by mysql support in Lifetime. 
Seems to be a bug on Opensuse 15.0 / 15.1 and Postfix 3.3.1.

Postfix never open any database connection. I think thats the same situation on your system.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/416192)

Comment: bjoster, as found out it is an generally bug and seems postfix was not build with ( m4 ) support.  This negative rating without any background is just irritating and useless. Doesn't help and my answer describes / confirms an general problem on opensuse 15.x. thx for you support.